# returning a pointer to an IXMLDOMNode as a parameter...what a pain

Tags: c++, dom

I have to polish up my c++ Knowledge, since we have to realize a specific module with MS vc++. OK, here is what I like to do:
I have a global MS DOMDocument which holds a number of nodes. These nodes are describing the object data... I receive a uniquie objectidentifier and have to search the DOM for the object  and map this to a given structure...

so I have this:

```
IXMLDOMNode *Node = NULL;
 if (FindObject(objectIdentifier, &Node))
{
nreturn = MapObject(Node, &pVarBind->value);
}
```

This should define a pointer to a node and calls the FindObject Method with the reference of the pointer. If it succeeds the MapObject method is called..
However "Node" is always NULL after Findobject, but inside the method it finds it object and tries to pass it back...

Findobject Looks like this:

```
bool MyController::FindObject(const string aObjectIdentifier, IXMLDOMNode **aObject)    
{
    bool success = false;
    IXMLDOMNode *pXMLEntry = NULL;
//....searching the DOM
    if (success)
    {
        aObject = &pXMLEntry;
    }
return success;
}
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: I suspect your code snippet lost something in translation... should your IXMLDOMNode parameter actually be called 'aMIBObject' instead of 'aObject'?

Comment: sorry my mistake....I corrected it...

Answer (score 3):

In FindObject, when you assign

```
aObject = &pXMLEntry;
```

What you're doing is overwriting your local parameter. What you want to do is write to the value pointed at by your parameter, like this:

```
*aObject = pXMLEntry;
```